# Android Studio says I'm not on gradle build, but I am

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

So I've just imported an app into Android Studio. It says

```
"Migrate Project to Gradle? This project does not use the Gradle build 
system. We recommend that you migrate to using the Gradle build system."
```

However... it appears I am on the gradle system. I see

```
build.gradle
```

files at the app-level etc, so? This is causing issues when I try to run the module (getting AndroidManifest.xml does not exist error, which I apparently need to solve by synching the gradles... except that button doesn't exist because Android Studio thinks I'm not using the gradle system.)

Help?

Comment: have you tried rebuilding the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to re-import your project in Android Studio:

1. Close your project
2. Back up your project
3. Delete the .idea folder in the root directory of the project
4. Delete all the .iml files in your project
5. Import your project in Android Studio, and in the dialog that
   prompts you for a file, choose the build.gradle file.

Comment: The build.gradle file at the app level, or the root level? EDIT: When I try either, it says "Specified file already exists."

This is the result of clicking on "Import project (Gradle...)"

Comment: Tried it with "From existing project" instead and it seems to be working, i.e. the "Gradle Daemon" is running